# Proving supremum of measure equals infimum in completion of measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let
>   $\mathcal{F}_{\mu}$ be the completion of $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to
>   $\mu$. For every $A \subset \Omega$, we define
>
> $$\mu_{0}(A) = \sup\{\mu(B) \mid B \in \mathcal{F}, B \subset A\} $$
>
> $$\mu^{0}(A) = \inf\{\mu(B) : B \in \mathcal{F} \mid B \supset A\} $$
>
> Prove that for every $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\mu}$, it holds that
>
> $$\mu_0(A) = \mu^{0}(A) = \mu(A).$$
>
> Conversely, prove that if $\mu_0(A) = \mu^{0}(A)$, then $A \in
>  \mathcal{F}_{\mu}$.

This is a practice problem that I am given while I am studying for my probability exam. I am not so great with measure theory, and I have tried to solve this problem for quite a while with no luck. I was hoping someone would be able to help me solve this problem so that I can learn better for future problems.

I think that in real analysis, these are called the outer and inner measures, but I am not completely sure. I've just seen these terms used when I was trying to figure out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, $A \subset \Omega$. Define $A_F^+ := \bigcap_{B \in F; A \subset B} B$ and $A_F^- := \bigcup_{B \in F; B \subset A} B$. Then $\mu^0(A) = \mu(A_F^+)$ and $\mu_0(A) = \mu(A_F^-)$.

If $\mu^0(A)=\mu_0(A)$, then $0 = \mu^0(A)-\mu_0(A) = \mu(A_F^+ \setminus A_F^-)$. So as $A \setminus A_F^- \subset A_F^+ \setminus A_F^-$ we have that $A \setminus A_F^- \in F_\mu$ and has measure $0$. Thus $A \in F_\mu$ and $\mu^0(A)=\mu_0(A) = \mu(A)$.

If $A \in F_\mu$, then both $A \setminus A_F^- = \bigcap_{B \in F; B \subset A} (A\setminus B)$ and $A_F^+ \setminus A = \bigcap_{B \in F; A \subset B} (B\setminus A)$ have measure $0$. Thus $\mu^0(A)=\mu_0(A) = \mu(A)$.

Comment: How'd you get $A\setminus A_F^- \subset A^+_F \setminus A^-_F$?

Comment: @hom, I got it from $A \subset A_F^+$.

Comment: How can you conclude $A \in F_\mu$ given $A \setminus A_F^- \in F_\mu$ and has measure $0$?